# How to show products based on cities in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on e-commerce website in Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin. The problem is that I have to show products based on cities (currently I have two cities). The Flow of the site should be that when user come to the site he will be shown a popup box which contain a dropdown of cities, when user Select a city then city related products will be shown.

I have two solutions to complete this tasks:

1. Creating multi site: problem is that with this solution that I have to setup separate sites and all the sites have same look and feel and some products are common in all stores. this will make data redundant but also take time to setup, customize and products uploading on each site.
2. Second Solution is to create a filter that will show products on the shop based on user selected city. problem is with this solution I did not get it how to make filters and attribute in products and make search them, I searched out plugins for this task but did not find any to solve this problem.

The theme I am using superfood. I am stuck between in these solutions, I did not know which one is best for me and how to solve these related problems. 
I will be very grateful to give any clue or solution that you may think will suitable for me.

Comment: You should start adding a custom field in product single pages settings like a select field or a group of checkboxes with your cities. Your actual question is just too broad for StackOverFlow. Note that multisite is really not recommended with Woocommerce.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for you comment. yes you are right my question is too broad, sorry for that. can I set attribute named location, fetch products based on this attribute.Is it possible that I save location value from the popup in the frontend and save it some where, and on the shop page or product page I use that value to query products.

Comment: Don't use attribute, category or tag… just search how to add a custom product field (don't use ACF, use code as there is tons of examples in StackOverFlow). A good developer can make you this feature complete in some few hours.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Can I use custom fields to fetch products and show it on the shop page? I do not getting the idea where to hook condition and use these custom fields in query condition to get products.

Comment: Maybe it should be better for you to hire a developer for few hours.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I am really grateful for your help. :)